# on_message_delete() not always triggering | discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to write a script for generating multiple images using the Midjourney discord bot.
I've created my own discord bot using discord.py to process messages sent by Midjourney and detect when an image is done generating - Midjourney always deletes its message and sends a new one when image generation is completed, so I tried using `async def on_message_delete(message)` for that purpose and it does work.
However, it doesn't detect the removal of messages 100% of the time and I have no idea why. I don't think its the code's fault, as it doesn't even enter on_message_delete.
Everything else works smoothly.

My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from pathlib import Path
import time
TOKEN = "my token"


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')
    file_path = Path.cwd() / "info.txt"
    f = open(file_path, "w")
    f.write("")
    f.close()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == Midjourney_ID:
        if 'Image #1' in message.content or 'Image #2' in message.content or 'Image #3' in message.content or 'Image #4' in message.content:
            print("Upscaling ready.")
            time.sleep(5)
            file_path = Path.cwd() / "info.txt"
            f = open(file_path, "w")
            f.write("end")
            f.close()


@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):

    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if message.author.id == Midjourney_ID:
        print(f"{message.author} finished generating the image.")
        time.sleep(5)
        file_path = Path.cwd() / "info.txt"
        f = open(file_path, "w")
        f.write("end")
        f.close()


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

My bot communicates with the rest of the script through a txt file.

I've tried using on_raw_message_delete instead, but it seems its not a problem related to caching, and wait_for() inside both functions, but it didn't solve the problem.

EDIT: switching the order of on_message with on_message_delete seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: Sync `time.sleep` is blocking, change to async `asyncio.sleep`